# Opacity colors in Highcharts (with default color)

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

In highcharts there is a possibility to add color into the series. So you could say that a particular data in the series, has `color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.5)'`

```
series: [{
         name: 'Tokyo',
         data: [95.6, 54.4]

      }, {
         name: 'New York',
         data: [106.6, 92.3]

      }, {
         name: 'London',
         data: [59.3, 51.2]

      }, {
         name: 'Berlin',
         data: [46.8, 51.1],
         color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.5)'

      }]
```

However, I just want to tell highcharts to set opacity in a particular data. I want it to use the default color that it would use.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the demo code in [gradient fill](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient) you can customize the colors you want to use. You can put [rgba colors](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) here.